# Django ORM search in text by keywords with Subquery

Tags: django, orm, subquery

I have two models in django. Article model that have field title, and Keyword model with field title. I need to make query to DB and filter only those articles whose title contains any keyword from Keyword model. I try to search with Subquery, but it's doesn't work.

If I try to `filter` id's with `in` it's work:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery

Article.objects.filter(id__in=Subquery(Keyword.objects.values('id')))
```

But if I try to `filter` with `icontains` it's dosn't work:

```
Article.objects.filter(title__icontains=Subquery(Keyword.objects.values('title')))
```

Last query returns empty queryset
How fix it?

Comment: The above will give you `Article`s that contain *all* the keywords, and in that specific order.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to do this with two queries: one query to obtain all the `Keyword`s, then one that filters the `Article`s with this keyword, like:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

kws = Keyword.objects.values_list('title', flat=True)
articles = Article.objects.filter(
    reduce(or_, [Q(title__icontains=kw) for kw in kws])
)
```

The above can however result in a huge query, since we first load all titles.

An alternative is to make a `JOIN` with `.extra`, and then perform a "raw" SQL query annotation:

```
Article.objects.extra(
    tables=[Keyword._meta.db_table]
).annotate(
    key_title=RawSQL('{}.{}'.format(Keyword._meta.db_table, Keyword.title.field_name), ())
).filter(title__icontains=F('key_title'))
```

This will then result in a query like:

```
SELECT article.id, article.title, (keyword.title) AS key_title
FROM article , keyword
WHERE article.title LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(((keyword.title)), '\\\\', '\\\\\\\\'), '%', '\\%'), '_', '\\_'), '%')
```

The `REPLACE(..)` parts are here to *escape* the keyword title, since if it contains a `%`, this could result in a "wildcard" in a `LIKE` expression. This is all introduced by the `__icontains` lookup, so we do not need to worry about this.

Comment: amazing. Thanks, this is what I was looking for. It works ... I used a string with extra, but I don’t know how such constructions can be designed in a head. Thanks a lot.